# 2D API or OpenGL ES for an Android 2D game?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, 2d

I'm planning to develop a 2D game for Android devices without a dedicated GPU, like the HTC Wildfire. I remember from the PC that OpenGL is generally to be chosen over something like SDL for 2D graphics because of speed and features.

On Android, there are two APIs for graphics:

- A "normal" 2D API (does it have a name?)
- OpenGL ES 2.0

Which one should I favor for a 2D game that should run on Android devices without a dedicated GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your experience and the scope of the game really, there are benefits and drawbacks for both.  I would watch the Chris Pruett Google IO Lectures, they helped me out a lot when I was first getting started with game dev on Android.

Personally I went with OpenGL over the canvas (or "normal" as you called it) since I was familiar with it already.  The game I am working on under this approach works pretty well (with threading and being careful of the GC) even on the old myTouch phones.

Comment: But what about the GPU, will OpenGL not be slower if I've got none? Can I use vector graphics with any of the approaches?